# jQuery load() issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-address

I have a page: `index.html` with some content:

```
<section id="content">
...
</section>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery (with jQuery Address) to update content without reloading from other HTML files with *the same* `section` tag with *the same* id.

I'm stucked with this:

```
  $.address.init(function(event) {
    console.log("init: " + $('[rel="address:' + event.value + '"]').attr('href'));
  }).change(function(event) {
    $("#content").load($('[rel="address:' + event.value + '"]').attr('href') + ' #content');
    console.log("change");
  });
```

It almost works. But! It inserts *one more* `<section id="content">` with `</section>`, so everything blows up.

How I can get rid of one `<section id="content">` + `</section>`?

Comment: Why are you calling `.html()` before `.load()`? Is it an *especial* `.html()`?

Comment: @Alexander: That was just some experiments with `.html` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.load()` use a combination of `$.get()` and `.replaceWith()`.

```
$('#content').html().load() ...
```

use

```
$.get({
  url:...,
  success:function(data) {
    $('#content').replaceWith( data )
  }
});
```